# How to transform an object in typescript?

Tags: javascript, typescript

if we having a object like this:

```
const item = {
   name: { value: "aa", mode: "b"},
   doc: { value: "bb", mode: "b"}
}
```

How can I transform the object to have something like that:

```
const transform= {
   name: "aa",
   doc: "bb"
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do it by iterating over the keys of the `item` object and take only the `value` from each element, then put it in the new object:

```js
let transform = {};
for (let key in item) {
    transform[key] = item[key].value;
}

// Prints it out as in your example
console.log(transform);
```

By the way, neither your code, nor my example solution use any features specific to typescript. This is pure javascript.

Answer (score 0):

Functional approach, without mutation:

```js
const item = {
   name: { value: "aa", mode: "b"},
   doc: { value: "bb", mode: "b"}
}

const result = Object.keys(item).reduce((acc,elem)=>({
   ...acc,
   [elem]:item[elem].value
 }),{})
```

NExt time, please publish also what have you tried